# EclipseNSIS: "An error occurred while automatically activating bundle net.sf.eclipsensis (491)"

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, nsis

I am trying to package my program to send to friends for playtesting. I installed the EclipseNSIS pluggin, but am getting an error when I attempt to create an installer:

The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in net.sf.eclipsensis was unable to load class net.sf.eclipsensis.wizard.NSISScriptWizard.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle net.sf.eclipsensis (491).

Here's a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b43Mw.png)

Any ideas? All are welcome. Thanks a bunch!

Edit: Here's the most recent log entry:

```
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 2 2015-07-03 14:34:49.616
!MESSAGE Problems encountered starting up plug-in: "org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module.".
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.start(InternalPlatform.java:919)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.doPluginActivation(PluginDescriptor.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.getPlugin(PluginDescriptor.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getPlugin(Platform.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.legacy.InitLegacyPreferences.init(InitLegacyPreferences.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferencesService.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.applyRuntimeDefaults(DefaultPreferences.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.load(DefaultPreferences.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.AbstractScope.getNode(AbstractScope.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.DefaultScope.getNode(DefaultScope.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.getDefaultPreferences(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.getPreferenceNodes(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.contains(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:356)
    at net.sf.eclipsensis.startup.FileAssociationChecker.initializePreference(FileAssociationChecker.java:197)
    at net.sf.eclipsensis.startup.FileAssociationChecker.addExtension(FileAssociationChecker.java:181)
    at net.sf.eclipsensis.startup.FileAssociationChecker.loadExtensions(FileAssociationChecker.java:125)
    at net.sf.eclipsensis.startup.FileAssociationChecker.<init>(FileAssociationChecker.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$56.run(Workbench.java:2755)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/eclipsensis/job/JobScheduler
    at net.sf.eclipsensis.installoptions.InstallOptionsPlugin.<init>(InstallOptionsPlugin.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle net.sf.eclipsensis (491).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in net.sf.eclipsensis.EclipseNSISPlugin.start() of bundle net.sf.eclipsensis.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: EclipseNSIS only supports Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7.
    at net.sf.eclipsensis.EclipseNSISPlugin.validateOS(EclipseNSISPlugin.java:441)
    at net.sf.eclipsensis.EclipseNSISPlugin.start(EclipseNSISPlugin.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: EclipseNSIS only supports Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7.
    at net.sf.eclipsensis.EclipseNSISPlugin.validateOS(EclipseNSISPlugin.java:442)
    ... 72 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/eclipsensis/job/JobScheduler
    at net.sf.eclipsensis.installoptions.InstallOptionsPlugin.<init>(InstallOptionsPlugin.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.start(InternalPlatform.java:919)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.doPluginActivation(PluginDescriptor.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.getPlugin(PluginDescriptor.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getPlugin(Platform.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.legacy.InitLegacyPreferences.init(InitLegacyPreferences.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferencesService.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.applyRuntimeDefaults(DefaultPreferences.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.load(DefaultPreferences.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.AbstractScope.getNode(AbstractScope.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.DefaultScope.getNode(DefaultScope.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.getDefaultPreferences(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.getPreferenceNodes(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.contains(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:356)
    at net.sf.eclipsensis.startup.FileAssociationChecker.initializePreference(FileAssociationChecker.java:197)
    at net.sf.eclipsensis.startup.FileAssociationChecker.addExtension(FileAssociationChecker.java:181)
    at net.sf.eclipsensis.startup.FileAssociationChecker.loadExtensions(FileAssociationChecker.java:125)
    at net.sf.eclipsensis.startup.FileAssociationChecker.<init>(FileAssociationChecker.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$56.run(Workbench.java:2755)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle net.sf.eclipsensis (491).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in net.sf.eclipsensis.EclipseNSISPlugin.start() of bundle net.sf.eclipsensis.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: EclipseNSIS only supports Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7.
    at net.sf.eclipsensis.EclipseNSISPlugin.validateOS(EclipseNSISPlugin.java:441)
    at net.sf.eclipsensis.EclipseNSISPlugin.start(EclipseNSISPlugin.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: EclipseNSIS only supports Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7.
    at net.sf.eclipsensis.EclipseNSISPlugin.validateOS(EclipseNSISPlugin.java:442)
    ... 72 more
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Comment: @greg-449 ok I just updated it.

Comment: The log suggests it does not like you OS - "EclipseNSIS only supports Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7"

Comment: @greg-449 hmm I didn't suspect that bc windows 8.1 supposedly emulates windows 7, but thanks. How would you go about packaging then?